# Krita does not uninstall from Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS

Tags: 20.04, uninstall, krita

I installed Krita on my Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS. I don't remember how I installed it. It's a very complicated software and my use case is very simply. Therefore I wish to uninstall it.

For uninstalling it I issued the command in the terminal

```
$ sudo apt-get remove krita
```

but my terminal replied

> Package 'krita' is not installed, so not removed

I even tried

```
$ sudo apt-get purge krita-data
```

But that doesn't work either.

How do I uninstaller this stickler from my system.

Comment: `snap remove krita` ?

Comment: @DanielT Post it as answer. I will accept it. Thanks.

Comment: FYI: Software installed from the software center are often installed as snaps instead of debs.

Comment: The Snap Store and its consequences have been a disaster for the human race

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ubuntu's software installation GUI may decide to install the snap version of packages. In this case, you can remove Krita with the following command:

```bash
sudo snap remove --purge krita
```

The two main packaging methods on Ubuntu are debs and snap. In your question, you showed that Krita was not installed through apt/debs. Flatpaks and AppImages are less common and it was unlikely that you would forget installing Krita those ways. That leaves snap as the only possibility left, which you could verify with `which krita`